# Remote debugging Azure for API Webapp in VS 2015 - Symbols are not loaded

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, azure-web-app-service

I have a webapp running hosting webapi's. I need to debug the webapp. I'm using the following setup:

- Visual Studio 2015 update 3, running in administrator mode
- Azure tools 2.9
- On the webapp I have turned remote debugging for VS2015 and set the platform to 64 bit (to prevent mismatch with VS)
- Deployed the solution in debug mode (the PDB's are on Azure)
- Attach debugger via the server explorer (cloud explorer gives a very generic error). Attatching seems to be going allright, because I see the steps pass by without errors
- Make a call to the API -> no breakpoint is hit. Expected because the breakpoint is white saying  "The breakpoint will not currenty be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Restarted the webapp a few times, no effect.
I have had the same process working be for on my previous development machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

1. Clean and then Rebuild the project in Debug mode.
2. Republish the project
3. Make sure that the debug attribute of the compilation element in the Web.config file is set to **true**:

I hope this may help